# How to call pre-existing WebAssembly code from Emscripten

Tags: javascript, c, webassembly, emscripten

I've made a [compiler](https://github.com/FlatAssembler/AECforWebAssembly) from my programming language (called AEC) targeting WebAssembly. However, that compiler only produces WebAssembly Binary Toolkit (WABT) compatible code, as I couldn't find sufficient documentation for the assembly compatible with Emscripten. So, how can I call the functions in that language from Emscripten-compatible C or C++?
Previously, I made a compiler for that language targeting x86, and it was [rather easy](https://github.com/FlatAssembler/ArithmeticExpressionCompiler/tree/master/recursive_HybridSort) to use C++ to interact with code written in that language. The same, however, doesn't seem to be true when using WebAssembly.
Let's say I have this code in AEC:

```
Function plusOne(Integer32 integer) Which Returns Integer32 Does
    Return integer + 1;
EndFunction
```

I compile it as follows:

```
[teo.samarzija@teos-acer-laptop debug]$ ../AECforWebAssembly/aec *.aec
Running the tests...
All the tests passed.
Reading the file...
All characters read!
Tokenizing the program...
Finished tokenizing the program!
Parsing the program...
Finished parsing the program!
Compiling the program...
Compilation finished!
Saving the assembly in file "plusOne.wat"...
Assembly successfully saved, quitting now.
[teo.samarzija@teos-acer-laptop debug]$ wat2wasm plusOne.wat
```

Now, let's say I want to call it from a C code such as this one:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

extern int plusOne(int);

int main() {
    printf("plusOne(4)=%d\n",plusOne(4));
    return 0;
}
```

How do I compile the C program to be able to do that? If I try it in an analogous way I could do it with my AEC compiler targeting x86 assembly, I get this error:

```
[teo.samarzija@teos-acer-laptop debug]$ emcc -o test.html test.c plusOne.wasm
emcc: error: plusOne.wasm: Input file has an unknown suffix, don't know what to do with it!
```

So, what should I do?
The following NodeJS code accomplishes what I want:

```js
const FileSystem = require('fs');
const wasmFileContent = FileSystem.readFileSync("plusOne.wasm");
let stack_pointer = new WebAssembly.Global({value : 'i32', mutable : true}, 0);
let memory = new WebAssembly.Memory({initial : 1, maximum : 1});
let importObject = {
  JavaScript : {stack_pointer : stack_pointer, memory : memory}
};
WebAssembly.instantiate(wasmFileContent, importObject).then((results) => {
  const exports = results.instance.exports;
  let plusOne = exports.plusOne;
  console.log("plusOne(4)=", plusOne(4));
});
```

So, how can I do that in C or C++ using Emscripten?

Comment: Would it be sufficient to put the linking code in your C/C++ source using EM_JS or EM_ASM? I'm not sure you can do it directly from Emscripten